# jitter geom_line()

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Is there a way to jitter the lines in `geom_line()`? I know it kinda defies the purpose of this plot, but if you have a plot with few lines and would like them all to show it could be handy. Maybe some other solution to this *visibility* problem.

Please see below for code,
[image: jitter geom_line]

```
A  <- c(1,2,3,5,1)
B  <- c(3,4,1,2,3)
id <- 1:5
df <- data.frame(id, A, B)


# install.packages(reshape2)
require(reshape2) # for melt
dfm <- melt(df, id=c("id"))

# install.packages(ggplot2)
require(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = id, 
color= as.factor(id))) + geom_line() + labs(x = "id # 1 is hardly 
visible as it is covered by id # 5") + scale_colour_manual(values = 
c('red','blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black')) 


p2 <- ggplot(subset(dfm, id != 5), aes(x = variable, y = value, 
group = id, color= as.factor(id))) + geom_line() + labs(x = "id # 
5 removed, id # 1 is visible") + scale_colour_manual(values = 
c('red','blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'black')) 

# install.packages(RODBC)
require(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(p1, p2)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can try

```
geom_line(position=position_jitter(w=0.02, h=0))
```

and see if that works well.

Comment: I like this solution, I'll try it out on my real data tomorrow (when I get back to the lab). Did you try it with my code?

Comment: yes I did, but whether you prefer vertical or horizontal jitter will depend on your data, I think. Also, it may not be a good idea to jitter everything if you only want one line jittered.

Comment: consider also ``position_dodge()`` to avoid overlap - see my answer below

Answer (score 30):

If you just want to prevent two lines from overlapping exactly, there is now a better way: [position_dodge()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/position_dodge.html), which "adjusts position by dodging overlaps to the side". This is nicer than adding jitter to any line, even when it's not needed.

### Avoid ggplot2 lines overlapping exactly using position_dodge()

Code example:

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,z=1:10);
df.m <- melt(df, id.vars = "x");
ggplot(df.m, aes(x=x,y=value,group=variable,colour=variable)) 
    + geom_line(position=position_dodge(width=0.2));
```

Thanks to `position_dodge()`, we can now see that there are two lines in the plot, which just happen to co-incide exactly:

[image: prevent line overlap in ggplot with position_doge]

Comment: This would have been what I need, but for some reason it has been nerfed in the meantime. Now `position_dodge` takes only a `width` parameter without `height` (version 2.2.1), so it is not usable for distinguishing the horizontal bars in my pre-post-treatment spaghetti plot :( Still +1 for you, as it seems to be the closest to the answer I need.

Comment: @rumtscho thanks for the comment. For anyone else reading this, I just confirmed that the basic example above (for line plots) still works as it stands with ggplot 2.2.1

Answer (score 5):

I tend to use different linestyles, so that, say, a solid blue line "peeks through" a dashed red line on top of it.
Then again, it does depend on what you want to impart to the reader.  Keep in mind first and foremost that *data* should be points and *theory* lines unless this makes things cluttered. Unless the y *and* x values are identical, it'll be easier to see the points. (or you could apply the existing `jitter` function to the x-values) 
 Next,  if you just want to show which runs are in the "bundle" and which are outliers, overlap doesn't matter because it's very unlikely that two outliers will be near-equal.

If you want to show a bunch of near-equal runs, you may prefer (which is to say, your readers will understand better) to plot the deltas against a mean rather than the actual values.

Comment: I like your argument, but I'm unsure about how to apply it to my specific case. Could it be possible for you to supply some sample code or links to some visual examples?

Comment: @EricFail : the easiest way to apply jitter when plotting points is just `y_jit<-jitter(y_data)` and/or same for `x_data` and then feed the jittered data to your plotting code.  If you want to "jitter" lines, I'd go w/ baptiste's solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest a solution to a different problem than described, in which the Y axis is a factor, so position_dodge does nothing.

[image]

code:

```
library(tidyverse)

time_raw <- tibble(year=1900:1909,
            person_A=c(rep("Rome",2),rep("Jerusalem",8)),
            person_B=c(rep("Jerusalem",5),rep("Rome",5)))


achievements <- tribble(~year,~who,~what,
                  1900,"person_A","born",
                  1900,"person_B","born",
                  1909,"person_A","died",
                  1909,"person_B","died",
                  1905,"person_A","super star",
                  1905,"person_B","super star")

SCALE=0.5

jitter_locations <- time_raw %>%
  pivot_longer(-year,names_to="who",values_to="place") %>%
  distinct(place)%>%
  filter(!is.na(place)) %>% 
  mutate(y_place=seq_along(place)) 

jitter_lines <- time_raw %>%
  pivot_longer(-year,names_to="who",values_to="place") %>%
  distinct(who) %>%
  mutate(y_jitter=scale(seq_along(who))*0.015)

data_for_plot <- time_raw %>% 
 pivot_longer(-year,names_to="who",values_to="place") %>% 
 filter(!is.na(place)) %>% 
 left_join(achievements) %>% 
 left_join(jitter_locations) %>% 
 left_join(jitter_lines)


 data_for_plot %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x=year,y=y_place+y_jitter,color=who,group=who))+
   geom_line(size=2)+
   geom_hline(aes(yintercept=y_place),size=50,alpha=0.1)+
   geom_point(data = . %>% filter(!is.na(what)),size=5)+
   geom_label(aes(label=what),size=3,nudge_y = -0.025)+
   theme_bw()+
   coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min(jitter_locations$y_place)-0.5*SCALE,
                       max(jitter_locations$y_place)+0.5*SCALE))+
   scale_y_continuous(breaks = 
   min(jitter_locations$y_place):max(jitter_locations$y_place),
                 labels = jitter_locations$place)+
   scale_x_continuous(breaks =  
   min(data_for_plot$year):max(data_for_plot$year))+

   ylab("Place")
```