# R ggplot overlapping lines to use matplotlib colour behaviour

Tags: r, matplotlib, ggplot2

When two lines coincide, matplotlib uses the "sum" of the two line colours, while ggplot uses colour from one line. The matplotlib way makes it clearer that the two lines are overlapping. Is it possible to make ggplot do the similar colouring?

Setting alpha sort of does that, but with alpha, the resulting colour is dominated by the top colour. (If alpha = 0.5, then top colour gets opacity 0.5 and under colour gets opacity 0.5 * 0.5.)

matplotlib

```
pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0,1,2,3, 4], 'B' : [-1, 0, 2, 3, 0]}).plot(title = 'matplotlib in python')
```

[image: matplotlib]

ggplot

```
dt = data.table(name = rep(c('A','B'), each = 5), 
                y = c(0,1,2,3,4,-1, 0, 2, 3, 0), 
                x = 1:5)
ggplot(dt) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, col = name)) + 
  ggtitle('ggplot in R')
```

[image: ggplot]

Comment: Note that matplotlib does not produce "the sum". This is just a visual side-effect of the antialiasing that matplotlib uses. The orange line still lies on top of the blue one; you can see that when turning antialiasing off.

Comment: I found the solution there "baptiste": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866047/jitter-geom-line